# Why can't you do a breakdown method for division in summation notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^5 i^2/5i$$

For this example, the answer is $3$ with simple plugging in and expansion.

However, upon calculating ${n^2}$ and ${5n}$ separately and dividing I come up with:

$$\sum_{i=1}^5 i^2 =  \frac {5(6)(11)}{6} =55 $$

$$\sum_{i=1}^5 5i = 5(\frac {5(6)}{2}) = 75 $$

$55/75$ is not 3.

What refutes my breakdown method?

Comment: What supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\frac a c + \frac b c \ne \frac {a + b} {c + d}$$ (which is what you silently use in your mistaken calculation).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the sum of two (or multiple) fractions does not equal the sum of the numerator / sum of the denominator.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!